# Laravel put null in created_at and updated_at while inserting new record

Tags: laravel, null

I don't know why, but when I want to insert something:

```
users::insert([
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'last_name' => $last_name,
    'remember_token' => $remember_token,
]);
```

It just inserts NULL into created_at and updated_at columns.
I have tried these:

```
'create_at' => time(),
'updated_at' => time(),

'create_at' => '',
'updated_at' => '',

'create_at' => TRUE,
'updated_at' => TRUE,
```

But none of them worked, but just TRUE put 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Comment: maybe you have accidentaly set $timestamps to false in your model?

Comment: Thanks, It should have worked without specifying, but I have set it to true either.

Comment: so did it start working?

Comment: no, why should it start when I haven't done anything?

Comment: Are you creating a new record?

Comment: And is `users` the name of your Model?

Comment: @AryaBasiri Have you tried this `'created_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now()` ?

Comment: Yes that inserts correctly, but just created_at and updated_at are always null. I even change structure to datetime instead of timestamp that is default, but it didn't work either

Comment: @DoanTran Thanks, it worked, but I thought if I don't put anything for that, it puts date and time correctly, Is there anyway not to use that Carbon?

Answer (score 6):

The timestamp columns (created_at and updated_at) will be assigned automatically only if you are using the Eloquent like so:

```
$user = new \App\User;
$user->first_name = $first_name;
$user->last_name = $last_name;
$user->save();
```

When you are using query builder, you have to `created_at` and `updated_at` value by yourself:

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'first_name' => $first_name,
    'last_name' => $last_name,
    'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
    'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
]);
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: No, I used first one exactly what you typed, again it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

In the Model you should  add this code,

```
public $timestamps = true;
```

created_at and updated_at will be updated automatically

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `create` method instead of `insert` method. Create method automatically add timestamp for created_at and updated_at field.

From Rakesh Nandi answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54302128/3740246